# Recording avplayer playing live streaming byte data...in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to save avplayer playing byte data save on document directory.(like recording) but i don't want record side voice only song music.

AVAudioRecorder is take speaker voice so, thats why i want to save player live streaming data.

So, Please give any suggestion and source code which apply in my code.